# How to convert binary image data saved in db and display in browser

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, image

so i am creating a web app that allows users to post images and i save the images as binary using multer into my mongo database, now i want to retrieve the images and render it on the webpage but the images dont show when i use the img tag, please do you know how i can transform binary image data to normal webpage readable image format, just found out i cant use "fileSystem" in react and i was wondering if there is anyway i could do this or any snippet of code i could use to complete this task, thanks!

Comment: My first top-of-my-head thought is to create a data img tag.  You can encode the data and put it directly into the HTML image tag. `<img src="DATA GOES HERE">`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html

Comment: Have a look here: https://codeburst.io/image-uploading-using-react-and-node-to-get-the-images-up-c46ec11a7129

Answer (score 1):

If you can't/don't want to store it as a regular file and serve it, you could try displaying it using base64 format. You can find more about it here: [How to display Base64 images in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)

But in simple words, you simply have to display a tag like this `<img src="data:image/png;base64,base 64 here ..." />`

But I strongly suggest that you should use some file upload functionality instead of saving the raw bytes to the database.

Comment: okay, thanks from a comment i saw, i think i will save the image as a normal blob from now on

Answer (score 0):

We can use an third party app to upload a file .

1. File is send from browser to server .
2. Server stores that file in its temporary disk .
3. Server sends file to cloud storage .
4. Cloud storage sends an URL of image .
5. URL is stored in DB of server .